# SqlDataReader times out when many records in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure `Topounce` that gets the top record from a dynamic table and speaks it out of the PC. When the there are too many records it times out in

```
SqlDataReader dr2 = select.ExecuteReader()
```

Right now there are around 750 records. I already tried `CommandTimeOut = 0` and it took around 10 min for the record to be spoken. Is there a way around this?

Here is the error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Code:

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection connStr2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString))
   {
      //Selects top record from vwAnno
      SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Topounce", connStr2);
      select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                   
      select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", (string)Num);

      connStr2.Open();

      SqlDataReader dr2 = select.ExecuteReader();   // TIMES OUT HERE

      //Reads record in vwAnnounce
      while (dr2.Read())
      {
          //do work
      }

      dr2.Close(); //Close Datareader connection
      connStr2.Close();
}
```

**UPDATE**
here is the store procedure.

```
     USE [Queue]
      GO
      /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TopRowViewAnnounce]    Script Date:         06/01/2013 11:55:50 ******/
       SET ANSI_NULLS ON
     GO
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     GO
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TopRowViewAnnounce] 
    @QueueID int

    AS


    BEGIN

 SELECT TOP 1 id, qdate, ticket_number, QID, received, displaynum, station, transcodevoiced FROM vwAnnounce WHERE QID = @ID ORDER by received ASC
    END
```

The reason I did a store procedure its because I thought it was going to help the timeout. I originally had it like this.

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id, qdate, ticket_number, QID, received, displaynum, station, transcodevoiced FROM vwAnnounce WHERE QID = @ID ORDER by received ASC", connStr2);
  select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                   
  select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", (string)Num);

  connStr2.Open();

  SqlDataReader dr2 = select.ExecuteReader();   // TIMES OUT HERE
```

I still havent got the solution. Anybody?

Comment: can you post the stored procedure code ? 750 records is nothing it should not be that slow.

Comment: That is correct @SenadUka. 750 records are nothing.

Comment: It sounds to me like `Topounce` is the real problem here, not the data volume - *unless*, that is, the rows include large text/binary blobs (as in: muchos muchos bytes). How long does `Topounce` take to run normally? Is there any chance it is being impacted by different `SET` conditions from the ADO.NET code (the `SET` conditions can prevent things like persisted+calculated+indexed columns from working correctly, forcing a table-scan instead of an index-seek, for example)

Comment: @MarcGravell, I knew there is a vast room for query optimization with the stored procedure when I saw it took 10 minutes to return records. My queries on a 10 million records table takes roughly 200 milliseconds to return 1000 records.

Comment: Try running the same query in SQL Server Management Studio with option `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to see how long it takes.

Comment: I would also suggest running an execution plan to see where things could be optimized.

Comment: I updated the originally post. I posted the store procedure and the way I had it originally.

Answer (score 3):

Add `Connect Timeout=120` in your connection string.

By default connection time out is 30 secs.

Since, it is retrieving large number of records , you will need to increse that time in your accordance.

You Connection String can be:

```
data source=ServerName;initial catalog=DBName;uid=ID;pwd=Password;Connect Timeout=120
```

On IIS also you have `timeout` setting.

`IIS > Website tab > Connection time out box` .

Set the max timeout value (in secs) IIS should maintain idle connection .

Hope its helpful.

Comment: If I am not wrong, `Connect Timeout` is different than `Command Timeout`. Plus problem seems to be in the stored procedure.

Comment: The timeout problem is with **executing** the query - the `connect timeout` does not influence that in any way, shape or form. This is a timeout if **connecting** to the database is timing out...

Comment: @JayPatel nope, since i deal with large DBs of share market, i have faced this problem many times. When we increase connection time out, problem gets solved.

Comment: @marc_s let him try this once, i am sure, problem will get solved.

Comment: @Freelancer, but is it the best solution even if it did work? I think solving the core problem of inefficient query is the real solution.

Comment: @JayPatel may be you are right, i dont know about which one will be the best. I only knows, when this problem arrived to me, each time i have done these things and problem get solved.

Comment: I updated the originally post. I posted the store procedure and the way I had it originally.